# Git fatal not valid : is this a git repository?

Tags: git

I got this error when I'm trying to push my commit

```
fatal: http://username@servernet:8000/scm/~user/filename.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

I don't know why the link changed and those /info/refs  dirs added. and how to remove them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this solved my problem :

```
git remote set-url origin [REPO-URL]
```

Answer (score 1):

check if your proxy is on from your PC settings,
if on toggle/switch it off

then reconnect to your network

in your terminal after setting it to the right repositories, if still not working
try
git fetch --all

enter git push again
it should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add origin master and try pushing the changes again

Answer (score 0):

add remote url again with:

```
$ git remote add some_othername url_here
```

or You can remove the remote origin by

```
$ git remote remove origin
```

then add the remote origin again.

Comment: You won't be able to add the remote origin again so you can add with some other name or remove the remote origin and then add a remote named origin again. see the edit